# Selenium: JUnit4: WebDriver: IE: NoSuchElementException when using IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I recorded my test in Selenium IDE; it runs fine in Firefox and Chrome.  When I run it in IE 9, I keep getting this error.  I am new to coding and am having trouble finding an answer to this.  If anyone can explain to me in lay man's terms what is happening/why this may be the case, I'd appreciate it.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == BODY (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Java Code:

```
assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*Final[\\s\\S]*$"));
```

Comment: could you please paste ur html code for your web page here?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post our code by company policy.  I figured that error, and the explanation of what is happening might be enough that someone might have seen similar things.  I appreciate your quick reply though.  It is appreciated.

Comment: What about StackOverflow Policies?

Comment: @user1806215, no. There isn't enough information. You've given valid Java code, and a valid set of WebDriver commands. That's all we can tell from this. I would question what's wrong with posting a small section of your HTML page, providing it has no personal information. Two things I would say, try with XPath and verify this only happens in the IE Driver. Also question why you need the `body` tag specifically in the first place.

Comment: @user1806215 - Can you post a little bit code, so that we can provide you correct solution for that, this line is not enough. Please dummy code so we can see and give proper answer.

Comment: I have the same problem, with the same restriction in terms of posting code. I did try running a test against the Google page using Selenium 2.25 using the IEDriver and got the same problem. Selenium seems unable to recognize the tags using the exact same expressions that work in Firefox.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? In Eclipse, put a breakpoint at the line which fails and let it run - it will pause before executing that line. Then you can use the debugging panels to run ad hoc lines of code, for example to check if you can find the element by css selector or by any other identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest printing out driver.getPageSource() before the call and check to see if the html that is on the current page matches your expectations.

If it does match what you'd expect then I'd print out the text content of all of the tags that match `By.cssSelector("BODY")` and see if any of them contain the text that you'd expect.

This will narrow down where the error is - you might need to find another way of finding this element.

Answer (score 0):

Internally By uses XPath and casing matters with internet explorer.

Try using

```
assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*Final[\\s\\S]*$"));
```

instead of

```
assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*Final[\\s\\S]
```

*$"));

I believe that should work for you.

Comment: It is an old post, but thought it might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

IE browser doesn't support Case-insensitive CSS attribute selectors. Try to use

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
```